# Why is casting from a string to float faster than string to int?

Tags: python, time, casting

Something surprising I just discovered:

```
>>> def f():
...  float('1')
...
>>> def i():
...  int('1')
...
>>> timeit(f, number=1000000)
0.22292590141296387
>>> timeit(i, number=1000000)
0.4127480983734131
```

I repeated this many times.  `float` always performs substantially better than `int`.  Why is this happening?  What goes on behind the scenes?

Comment: Just tested `%timeit float('1')` and `%timeit int('1')` in IPython (3) and got opposite results, `int` somewhat faster than `float`...